# Torus triangulation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, polyhedra

I'd like to plot something similar to this but with a triangle instead of a pentagon.

Also, I'd like to triangulate the faces, that is, to insert the diagonals for each face of the 3 prisms used.

In fact, I'd like to plot the minimal simplicial complex for the torus.

I tried to compute the vertices to use some polygon Plot3D function but no progress. Sorry.

[image: torus]

**Edit:**

Here is the code I have. I'm trying to see the 3 cycles to determine the faces. The problem is that they are not equilateral triangles.

```
pic3 = Graphics3D[{Green, 
   Polygon[{{0, -1, Sqrt[3] - 1}, {1, -1 - Sqrt[3], 
      Sqrt[3] - 2}, {-1, -1 - Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3] - 2}}]}]; 
pic2 = Graphics3D[{Pink, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0, Sqrt[3]}}]}];
pic1 = Graphics3D[{Blue, 
    Polygon[{{0, 1, Sqrt[3] - 1}, {1, 1 + Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3] - 2}, 
             {-1, 1 + Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3] - 2}}]}];
```

[image: my attempt]

**Edit 2:**

Using some rotation transformation, I defined some points and rotated them to produce another triangles. The code below produces a better result.

Now I'd like to make it fancier, maybe with transparent or glass style.

```
triang1 = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1 + Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0, 1 + Sqrt[3]}};
triang2 = RotationTransform[2 Pi/3, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}][triang1];
triang3 = RotationTransform[4 Pi/3, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}][triang1];

pic1 = Graphics3D[{Blue, Polygon[triang1]}];
pic2 = Graphics3D[{Red, Polygon[triang2]}];
pic3 = Graphics3D[{Green, Polygon[triang3]}];

trapez1 = {triang1[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[2]], triang1[[2]]};
Gtrapez1 = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon[trapez1]}];
trapez2 = {triang1[[1]], triang3[[1]], triang3[[2]], triang1[[2]]};
Gtrapez2 = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon[trapez2]}];
trapez3 = {triang3[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[2]], triang3[[2]]};
Gtrapez3 = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon[trapez3]}];
trapez4 = {triang1[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[3]], triang1[[3]]};
Gtrapez4 = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon[trapez4]}];
trapez5 = {triang1[[1]], triang3[[1]], triang3[[3]], triang1[[3]]};
Gtrapez5 = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon[trapez5]}];
trapez6 = {triang3[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[3]], triang3[[3]]};
Gtrapez6 = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon[trapez6]}];

Show[Gtrapez6, Gtrapez5, Gtrapez4, Gtrapez3, Gtrapez2, Gtrapez1,
     pic1, pic2, pic3, Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: my second attempt]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update 2:** A function to generate tori:

```
 toroidalF[n_, h_: (1/4), w_: (1/2), opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Module[{top, bottom, verts,
           outer = {Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n],
           faceverts = Flatten[#[[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] & /@ # & /@
                            (Join @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ 
                               Thread[{#, # + n + 1, # + 2 n + 2} &@
                                  Partition[Range[n + 1], 2, 1]]), 1]},
          top = # + {0, 0, h} & /@ (w outer);
          bottom = # + {0, 0, -h} & /@ (w  outer);
          verts = Join[outer, top, bottom];
          Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[], 
                      GraphicsComplex[verts, Polygon /@ faceverts]}, opts]]
```

Examples:

```
 Row[toroidalF[#, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ {3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

[image]

```
 Row[toroidalF[#, 1/5, 3/4, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ {3, 6, 9, 12}]
```

[image]

Stealing @Junho Lee's lighting `l`:

```
 Row[toroidalF[#, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 250, Lighting -> l] & /@ {3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

[image]

---

A brute-force approach to get the torus

```
 outer = {Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/3];
 top = # + {0, 0, 1/4} & /@ (.5 outer);
 bottom = # + {0, 0, -1/4} & /@ (.5 outer);
 verts = Join[outer, top, bottom];
 faceverts = Flatten[#[[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] & /@ # & /@ 
                 (Join @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@
                   Thread[{#, # + 4, # + 8} &@Partition[Range[4], 2, 1]]), 1];
 polygons = Polygon /@ faceverts;
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[], GraphicsComplex[verts, polygons]}, 
            Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Update:** Triangulation of rectangular faces:

```
faceverts2 = Join @@ (Join @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ 
                  Thread[{#, # + 4, # + 8} &@Partition[Range[4], 2, 1]]);
triverts = Flatten[{#, RotateLeft@#} & /@ faceverts2, 1][[All, ;; 3]];
polygons2 = Polygon /@ triverts;
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], GraphicsComplex[verts, polygons2]},
           Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

---

**Triangulation of faces using V10** on Wolfram Programming Cloud:

```
rR = BoundaryMeshRegion[verts, polygons];
HighlightMesh[rR,
      {Style[2, Directive[Opacity[.5],LightBlue]] ,Style[1,Directive[Thick,Blue]]}]
```

[image]

```
tm= TriangulateMesh[rR, MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity], MeshQualityGoal->"Minimal"];
HighlightMesh[tm, 
        {Style[2, Directive[Opacity[.5],LightBlue]],Style[1, Directive[Thick,Blue]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, very nice! Thanks. I have no idea about the code but it is pretty.

Comment: What a marvelous update!

Comment: Does your first block of code work on V9? I'm getting *Coordinate {ImageSize -> 250, 0, Boxed -> False} should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form.*

Answer (score 10):

This can also be done with the built-in plotting functions, *e.g.*

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
                 {2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]},
                 {t, 0, 2 Pi},
                 PlotPoints -> {4, 4}, MaxRecursion -> 0,
                 Mesh -> All,
                 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2]
                ]
```

[image: triangular torus]

Note the `PlotPoints` and the `MaxRecursion` options.

Comment: amazing!!! +++1

Comment: @kguler Have been always using this trick to generating meshes :)

Answer (score 9):

**Update: From your intuitive code**

**Step 1**
I deleted color of polygon in your code like this.

```
triang1 = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1 + Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0, 1 + Sqrt[3]}};
triang2 = RotationTransform[2 Pi/3, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}][triang1];
triang3 = RotationTransform[4 Pi/3, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}][triang1];

pic1 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[triang1]}];
pic2 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[triang2]}];
pic3 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[triang3]}];

trapez1 = {triang1[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[2]], triang1[[2]]};
Gtrapez1 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[trapez1]}];
trapez2 = {triang1[[1]], triang3[[1]], triang3[[2]], triang1[[2]]};
Gtrapez2 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[trapez2]}];
trapez3 = {triang3[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[2]], triang3[[2]]};
Gtrapez3 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[trapez3]}];
trapez4 = {triang1[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[3]], triang1[[3]]};
Gtrapez4 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[trapez4]}];
trapez5 = {triang1[[1]], triang3[[1]], triang3[[3]], triang1[[3]]};
Gtrapez5 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[trapez5]}];
trapez6 = {triang3[[1]], triang2[[1]], triang2[[3]], triang3[[3]]};
Gtrapez6 = Graphics3D[{Polygon[trapez6]}];
```

**Step 2** 
And I combined `Graphics3D`-s like following

```
graphics = {Gtrapez6, Gtrapez5, Gtrapez4, Gtrapez3, Gtrapez2, 
    Gtrapez1, pic1, pic2, pic3} /. Graphics3D -> Identity;

Graphics3D[graphics]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Step 3** 
I add lighting by using `Lighting` in the `Graphics3D`

```
A = RotationTransform[2 \[Pi]/3, {0, 0, 1}];
lp = {2, 1, 2};
l = {{"Point", Blue, lp},
   {"Point", Red, A@lp},
   {"Point", Green, A@A@lp}};

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], graphics},
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> l]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------

**Last: General Code**

**Step1**

I have made Torus like this

```
A = RotationTransform[2 \[Pi]/3, {0, 0, 1}];
vertex =
  Flatten[
   NestList[A, #, 2] & /@ {{1, 0, 1/2}, {5/2, 0, 0}, {1, 0, -1/2}}, 1];
poly =
  Flatten /@ (Flatten[
      Transpose /@ Partition[
        Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ Partition[Range[9], 3], 2, 1, 1]
      , 1] /. {a_, b_} :> {a, Reverse@b});
```

**Step2**

Use `Lighting` options in the `Graphics3D`.

```
lp = {3, 0, 0};
l = {{"Point", Red, lp},
   {"Point", Green, A@lp},
   {"Point", Blue, A@A@lp}};
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[vertex,
  {Opacity[0.3], Specularity[Orange, 50], Polygon /@ poly}],
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> l]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**An other light position**

```
lp = {3, 2, 2};
l = {{"Point", Blue, lp},
   {"Point", Red, A@lp},
   {"Point", Green, A@A@lp}};
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[vertex,
  {Opacity[0.3], Specularity[Orange, 50],
   EdgeForm[Thin], Polygon /@ poly}],
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> l]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Very beautiful view. Nice light also. Thanks so much. Unfortunately I'm not able to follow the code. As you see, my updated code is made by very intuitive pieces.

Comment: @Sigur I modified the code for understanding of you from your intuitive pieces. I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my own variation, which uses a modernized version of Roman Maeder's `MakePolygons[]`:

```
MakePolygons[vl_] /; ArrayQ[vl, 3] := Module[{dims = Most[Dimensions[vl]]}, 
  GraphicsComplex[Apply[Join, vl], Polygon[Flatten[Apply[Join[#1, Reverse[#2]] &, 
                  Partition[Partition[Range[Times @@ dims], Last[dims]], {2, 2}, {1, 1}],
                        {2}], 1]]]]

With[{n = 6, m = 3, c = 3, r = 1}, 
     Graphics3D[MakePolygons[ArrayPad[Map[Function[pt, Append[#1 pt, #2]],
                                          CirclePoints[n]] &
                                      @@@ (TranslationTransform[{c, 0}] /@
                                     (CirclePoints[{r, 0}, m])), {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
                                     "Periodic"]]]]
```

[image: triangulated torus]